# Can't get correct regex pattern to parse song info?

Tags: regex

I have the following line to process:

> ...playlist index:109 id:38522 title:Christmas in Heaven artist:B.B. King album:A Christmas Celebration of Hope playlist index:110 id:38523 title:I'll Be Home for Christmas artist:B.B. King album:A Christmas Celebration of Hope playlist index:111 id:38524 title:To Someone That I Love artist:B.B. King album:A Christmas Celebration of Hope playlist index:112 id:38525 title:Christmas Celebration artist:B.B. King album:A Christmas Celebration of Hope playlist index:113 id:38526 title:Merry Christmas, Baby artist:B.B. King album:A Christmas Celebration of Hope

The best pattern I have so far is:

```
playlist index:(?<index>\d+) id:(?<id>\d+) title:(?<title>[\w\s',]+) artist:(?<artist>[\w\s'.]+) album:(?<album>[\w\s']+)
```

but, it only matches every other one because `playlist` (of `playlist index`) is considered part of the previous album name.

Comment: So how about you tell us what you actually expect the result to be and what result you are currently getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Also, it's not very easy to read... You can put `>` at the beginning of your line to make it a blockquote, in StackOverflow markup!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplest fix

```
playlist index:(?<index>\d+) id:(?<id>\d+) title:(?<title>[\w\s',]+) artist:(?<artist>[\w\s'.]+) album:(?<album>[\w\s']+?)(?=$|\splaylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a positive lookahead to limit the number of characters the `album` part takes:

```
playlist index:(?<index>\d+) id:(?<id>\d+) title:(?<title>[\w\s',]+) artist:(?<artist>[\w\s'.]+) album:(?<album>[\w\s']+)(?= playlist index:|$)
                                                                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fY1wV6)

It basically makes sure that when the match ends, there's either `playlist index:` right after or the end of the line with `$`.

Comment: Probably also worth making the matches non greedy

Comment: @BobVale I'd rather leave it greedy since the album part is generally the longest, and if anything, I would rather have the other classes lazy and the album greedy, to minimize backtracking vs. checks hence going more easy on the regex engine working.